# Curl inside while loops 1

Tags: python-3.x

what is the difference between this code

```
x = 10
while x:
   x = x - 1
  if x % 2 == 0:
    print(x, end = ' ')
```

and this code

```
x = 10
while x:
  if x % 2 == 0:
    x = x - 1
    print(x, end = ' ')
```

I'v just start the python lerning thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try _running_ it?

Answer (score 1):

In the first code block:
You subtract `1` from `x` after every loop iteration, thus the value of `x` will be:

```
10 (outside the loop)
9
8
...
1
0
```

It will print `x` whenever `x` is even

```
8 6 4 2 0
```

The second code block will loop infinitely after the first iteration.
The inside of the `if` statement is executed only one when `x = 10`. After that, the value of `x` is always `9` and it stays like that infinitely.